# Hadoop Resourcemanager do not start on another cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

Hadoop 2.7.1

Main node is cloud1, and another node is cloud2.

I want to set like this.
cloud1 has Namenode, Datanode, Nodemanager.
cloud2 has Resourcemanager, Datanode, Nodemanager.

And I set up 'yarn-site.xml' like this.

```
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>cloud2</value>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>cloud2</value>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
```

But Resourcemanager starts locally.(In cloud1)

I don't know why this happens..

Please help.

Comment: refer to [yarn-default.xml][1] , for `<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>` you should specify port 8088.
and my main question is : how do you start hadoop demons?


  [1]: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

Comment: @masoumeh I'm starting hadoop daemons with this commands. 'sbin/start-dfs.sh', 'sbin/start-yarn.sh'

Comment: do you execute these commands on cloud1?

Answer (score 0):

refer to [Cluster Setup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) , you should configure `yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path` for nodemanagers' hosts and `yarn.resourcemanager.address` for resource manager's and `dfs.hosts` for data nodes' and `fs.defaultFS` for namenode's and do this on both of cloud1 and cloud2. notice that you should

> List all slave hostnames or IP addresses in your `etc/hadoop/slaves` file, one per line

to use 'sbin/start-dfs.sh', 'sbin/start-yarn.sh'. Do these instructions and tell me the result.